# OAuth SSO login with Google OAUTH2 stopped working

Tags: oauth-2.0, artifactory, google-oauth

We're using JFrog's Artifctory Pro.
The OAuth SSO has been working fine until today.

Now everyone who tries to login using his/her Enterprise Google account is getting:

```
Error 400: invalid_request
Invalid parameter value for approval_prompt: 'auto' is not valid
```

We've checked and double-checked all documentation about the OAuth SSO and Google OAuth2 on JFrog's and Google's documentation and cannot find any mistakes regarding URLs or endpoints anywhere.

Does anyone know what might be wrong and how to solve it?

What we could find is that `approval_prompt` and `auto` might be deprecated, so maybe Artifactory's OAuth2 implementation for Google is outdated?

Update 2020-04-22: JFrog seems to have solved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had that problem too, but it seems that it was a temporary problem.